# Apache2 won't run cgi files based on shebang

Tags: apache-http-server, python, cgi

I'm trying to use Python as the server-scripting language instead of PHP.

I've configured localhost and php files run fine under it.

If I create a file .../localhost/temp/test.cgi (making it executable):

```
#!/home/mike/python_venvs/test_venv369/bin/python

print( """Content-type:text/html\n\n
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html lang="en">
                <head>
                    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
TEST
                    <title>My server-side template</title>
                </head>
                <body>""" )
print( "</body></html>")
```

... it doesn't run as a Python script: the text of the file just gets displayed in the browser.

I've done quite a bit of searching on this. I have no such file, for example, as httpd.conf.  My Apache2 setup is like this: executable in /usr/sbin/apache2, with most configuration files apparently under /etc/apache2, and in particular, seemingly, /sites-available, where one finds two files, 000-default.conf and default-ssl.conf.

I may be mistaken, but I believe httpd.conf is the "old" Apache way of doing things.

I found a totally baffling but (just) possibly promising line at the bottom of 000-default.conf:

```
# For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
# enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
# include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
# following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
# after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
#Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf
```

... so I uncommented that and restarted the apache2 service. No difference.

Answer (score 0):

If the text of the script just gets displayed in the browser, it means that Apache has not been configured to understand cgi from that particular location.

See https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/howto/cgi.html - you need a directive somewhere that looks something like

```
<Directory "/var/www/localhost/temp/">
    Options +ExecCGI
</Directory>
```

Apache doesn't allow CGI by default, and the standard configuration examples expect CGIs to be in /cgi-bin/.

There are also several other ways to configure CGI, all documented on the link above - you'll have to see what applies to you.

According to https://code-maven.com/set-up-cgi-with-apache, the configuration file `serve-cgi-bin.conf` contains the following:

```
<IfModule mod_alias.c>
    <IfModule mod_cgi.c>
        Define ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
    </IfModule>

    <IfModule mod_cgid.c>
        Define ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN
    </IfModule>

    <IfDefine ENABLE_USR_LIB_CGI_BIN>
        ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/lib/cgi-bin/
        <Directory "/usr/lib/cgi-bin">
            AllowOverride None
            Options +ExecCGI -MultiViews +SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
            Require all granted
        </Directory>
    </IfDefine>
</IfModule>
```

So, you can see, if you enable that conf, you can still only serve CGI from /usr/lib/cgi. You should probably make a copy of this conf and adapt it to your specific needs.